# Wildfly 10 war Deployment

Tags: wildfly

i deployed war on wild fly 10 but its url is not working properly due to some configuration. Exposed war is deployed .As URL appending problem. see below images
main Page
[main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4orIE.png)
i clicked on link
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfjBm.png)

Comment: If I had to guess, the link for the forgot password page is wrong, and is being generated as http://jsp/...

Comment: the link is correct but url is not appending forward. as url is 192.168.150.81/i2coperation.war but when i choose an option or button its not loading content from furthur path e.g 192.168.150.81/i2coperation.war/a/b/imag.png not loading in front page but it opens a new context with /a/b/imag.png where it not found

Comment: I think @JohnAment is right. Can you show us the code for the main page? Specifically the `"Forgot your password"` link.